# Data verification when saving with Lightswitch

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

Right now I have a table I'm entering in spud date and release date. I want to verify that when adding a new row it looks in that current table to see if there is any other spud dates, to make sure the new spud date is later then the previous spud and also to verify that it has a release date before it adds a new row.  Anyone know how to do this.

```
if (this.ReleaseDate < SpudDate)
{
    results.AddPropertyError("Release Date cannot be before Spud Date");
}
```

I have this code in the validate function, but that's only when entering the current item. I also need to go back and view the other records to compare as well like I said.

```
     partial void ReleaseDate_Validate(EntityValidationResultsBuilder results)
      {
     IDataServiceQueryable<tblWellRigJunction> orders = (from o in  this.DataWorkspace.RigStatusData.tblWellRigJunctions
                                                            orderby o.ReleaseDate
                                                            where WellID.Equals(this.WellID)
                                                            select o).Take(1);

  foreach (tblWellRigJunction ord in orders)
        {

            if (ord.ReleaseDate.ToString() == "")
            {
                results.AddPropertyError("Previous Release Date entered is still null");
                return;
            }

            int result = DateTime.Compare(ord.SpudDate, this.SpudDate);

            if (result > 0)
            {
                results.AddPropertyError("Previous Spud Date is greater");
                return;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a simple query that takes all records in the table and sorts them by the spud date. If you sort the spud date by descending, you can then compare to the `.FirstOrDefault()`.

[image: Spud Date Query]

```
if (SpudDate < this.MySpudDates.FirstOrDefualt().SpudDate)
{
    results.AddPropertyError("New Spud Date cannot be before Previous Spud Date");
}
```

Comment: @Sirus You haven't described or shown enough of your code for me to tell you where to put it. If you're clicking a button to enter the data, do it in the `Button_Execute` method. Or if you're adding these to a grid, use a `foreach` to check each one in your `ScreenName_Saving` method.

Comment: When I go to save I have this.

  partial void ReleaseDate_Validate(EntityValidationResultsBuilder results)
        {

Comment: @Sirus Okay. What doesn't work? What is the error that you are receiving?

Comment: ok well I tried creating a query like you said. I tried to type in this.myspudates in the release_validate function but it doesn't show on intellisense therefore I can't use it ... if I use it on the screen (code) and not the datasource release function I can access the query but I don't want to do it on the screen.... this is my issue

Comment: also I need to check the previous release dates , based on the welllid so the spud date is not earlier then release

Comment: @Sirus If I add a `_Validate` method to one of my queries, the method stub is added to the screen/client code and I can access any of the queries I've made. Are you saying that your `_Validate` method is in the DataService/server code? And why don't you want to do it on the screen?